# AS3 1009 where is the error?

Tags: actionscript-3

So I have the following code:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;


public class Meteorek extends MovieClip {
            private var scena:Stage;
    public function Meteorek(scena:Stage,x:Number, y:Number ,z:Number): void {
        this.x = scena.stageWidth/2;
        this.y = scena.stageHeight/2;
        this.z = 1100;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, lasMeto ,false, 0, true);
    }
    public function lasMeto(e:Event):void{
        z -= 10;
        if(z<-100)
        {
        UsunZeScen();
        }
    }
    private function UsunZeScen() : void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, lasMeto);

        if (scena.contains(this))
                scena.removeChild(this);
    }
}
}
```

At the end I got an error message. And I don't know why. I have the same code in another class and everything works fine so whats wrong with this one? T
The error occurs at:

```
scena.removeChild(this)
```

Because it is too big.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please read the [faq]. It would be good of you to spend a bit of additional time to check your punctuation and spelling.

Comment: Error #1009 means you are trying to use or access a variable that is null. If the error occurs when trying to do `scena.removeChild(this);` it would mean that `scena` is null. But it seems impossible for `scena` to be null in your code, because that is passed into the constructor **and** the constructor uses it to get the stageWidth. If you run your code with the debug Flash Player it will get the exact line number where the error is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to constructor before listener:

```
this.scena = scena;
```